# Displaying results of list of changing length

Tags: excel, worksheet, displayobject, vba

I have a list of string values. The number of contents of the list keep changing, depends on the criteria selected by a user. I want to display the list in excel worksheet. What is the best way to do that? Should I use msgbox or Userform or something else?

Comment: See. my answer............only if I had a large number of items would I use a UserForm *(to get scrollbars.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **MsgBox** will be O.K., depending on your needs:

```
Sub DataItems()
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To n
        st = st & vbCrLf & Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
    MsgBox st
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a version that displays the items in a one-dimensional array:

```
Sub DataItems()
    ary = Array("John", "James", "Michael", "William", "George", "Nigel")
    For Each a In ary
        st = st & vbCrLf & a
    Next a
    MsgBox st
End Sub
```